# plot patch rectangle of range from different rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

I have a pandas dataframe similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2020',0.1,0.3,'cat1','csv'],\
                  ['1/1/2020',0.4,0.7,'cat1','excel'],\
                  ['1/1/2020',1.7,2.3,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0,0.3,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0.4,0.5,'cat2','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',0.5,0.7,'cat1','csv'],\
                  ['2/1/2020',1.1,1.3,'cat1','excel']],\
                     columns = ['date','start','end','cat','source'])
```

Each row of the df contains range of values to be colored and the color group (cat). I would like to plot the boxes on the same date on the same row in a graph:

[image]

Nice to have: It would be even better if the graph is interactive in a way that it can show a pop-up window showing the information of each color box (additional info that cannot be shown by color/location of the graph), for example:

```
Source: csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try plotting one bar after another:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    plt.barh(r['date'], width=r['end']-r['start'],
             left=r['start'], color='y' if r['cat']=='cat1' else 'g')
```

Or plot all of them together with mapping the color:

```
plt.barh(df['date'], width=df['end']-df['start'],
         left=df['start'], color=df['cat'].map({'cat1':'y', 'cat2':'g'}))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly on my actual data! May I know if there is any way to get a pop-up window to also show the source information?